# C# Httpwebrequest Log In System

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

The following code should log user in, but it does not work. The code uses 9gag as an example, but the general idea should work elsewhere too. The user does not get access his/hers profile.

What is wrong with the code?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


    namespace ttp_B
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            //string word_to_stop = "profile"; 
            string urltosite = "https://9gag.com/login"; // site that i'm trying to log in
            string emailaddress = "";
            string password = "";
            var coo = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            try
            {
                var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(urltosite) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
                request.CookieContainer = coo;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888); // fiddler 
                                                                 //some extra headers
                request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0";
                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer =
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            string.Format(
                                "csrftoken=&next=http%3A%2F%2F9gag.com%2F&location=1&username={0}&password={1}", emailaddress, password));
                    //this text of request is correct I guess. Got it from fiddler btw.
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                }
                using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    coo.Add(response.Cookies); // adding cookies, just to make this working properly
                    using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string http_code = sr.ReadToEnd(); // gettin' that new html document
                        //flag = (http_code.Contains(word_to_stop)); // looking for word that I'm sure exist after succesfull loggin' in
                                                                   //if(flag == true)
                                                                   //{
                                                                   //    console.writeline("Works");
                                                                   //}
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try the code, (with empty e-mail and empty password) it print "Works". The html that is returned contains the word_to_stop (profile), however, it is obvious that I did not log-in. Another thing, when you add the cookie container, you don't have to add the cookies received, they are already in the cookie container, you can check that yourself

Comment: Well variable word_to_stop is wrong then, btw. when I compilated the code and checked it's packets in fiddler I couldn't see same page (*using WebView) as I used to see when loggin' in with IE.

@edit probably going to use WebBrowser class, seems to be quite easier

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the request stream isn't closed before you go for the response.

simplified it should look like this:

```
var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
tStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

//close the stream
tStream.Close();

//go for the response
request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Well, I was able to read a response from the site without closin' the stream

Comment: but added it anyway, and in general it does not change anything